# KnockoutJS - Loading values to dropdown . Selected Value is null always

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

**Here goes my View model, which helps to load the items to drop down.** Items are getting loaded but when I inspect the element "value" attribute is empty. How can I get selected value?

```
$(function () {
  tss.Department = function (selectedItem) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable();
    self.description = ko.observable();
    self.isSelected = ko.computed(function () {
        return selectedItem() === self;
    });
    self.stateHasChanged = ko.observable(false);
  };
  tss.vm = (function () {
    var metadata = {
        pageTitle: "My App"
    },
    selectedDepartment = ko.observable(),
    departments = ko.observableArray([]),
    sortFunction = function (a, b) {
        return a.description().toLowerCase() > b.description().toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
    },
    selectDepartment = function (p) {
        selectedDepartment(p);
    },
    loadDepartments = function () {
        tss.departmentDataService.getDepartments(tss.vm.loadDepartmentsCallback);
    },
    loadDepartmentsCallback = function (json) {

        $.each(json, function (i, p) {
            departments.push(new tss.Department(selectedDepartment)
                    .id(p.DepartmentId)
                    .description(p.Description)
            );
        });
        departments.sort(sortFunction);
    };
    return {
        metadata: metadata,
        departments: departments,
        selectDepartment: selectDepartment,
        loadDepartmentsCallback: loadDepartmentsCallback,
        loadDepartments: loadDepartments,
        choices: choices,
        selectedChoice: selectedChoice
    };
})();

tss.vm.loadDepartments();
ko.applyBindings(tss.vm);
});
```

**Here is my HTML**

```
      <select data-bind="options:departments, value:selectDepartment, 
       optionsText: 'description', optionsCaption:'Select a product ...'">
      </select>
```

Also sorting is not happening. departmentDataService used to call external data. which has both "id" and "description"

I also tried setting value as 'Id', but did not work.

Comment: `selectedDepartment = ko.observable(),` you sure this is the right way ? something like this `selectedDepartment : ko.observable(),` or use `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use an additional function `selectDepartment` to pass the value to the observable, but instead directly bind the observable to the value property of the select-box:

```
<select data-bind="options:departments, value:selectedDepartment, ...
```

(remember to export the `selectedDepartment` observable)

The value property is not only used to communicate the current value from view to viewmodel, but also vice versa: to set the selected option. Binding to a function that provides only "write" functionality is therefore not sufficient.

If you need to react to changes of the selected department, you can subscribe to the observable (this is explained in the official docs).